# How do I change Ionic 4's ion-range pin font and formatting?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

As an example, I tried this in my global.scss file:

```
.range-pin {
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;

  &after:{
    content: " %";
  }
}
```

But this has no effect. I'm sure this has something to do with shadow root but I'm not sure what the right thing to do is here. Adding `ion-range .range-pin` to be more specific doesn't help either. How do I achieve this change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that the `ion-range` pin is part of the shadow dom, therefore we must use the SCSS variables that Ionic provides to customize the pin.

Unfortunately the Ionic Documentation doesn't always list all the variables, but looking at the master source code on Github for the range component, we can get an idea of what variables are currently available.

I look at the [range.md.scss file](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/range/range.md.scss) which contains the variables that are available for the range pin:

```
:host {
  --knob-border-radius: 50%;
  --knob-background: var(--bar-background-active);
  --knob-box-shadow: none;
  --knob-size: 18px;
  --bar-height: #{$range-md-bar-height};
  --bar-background: #{ion-color(primary, base, 0.26)};
  --bar-background-active: #{ion-color(primary, base)};
  --bar-border-radius: 0;
  --height: #{$range-md-slider-height};
  --pin-background: #{ion-color(primary, base)};
  --pin-color: #{ion-color(primary, contrast)};

  @include padding($range-md-padding-vertical, $range-md-padding-horizontal);

  font-size: $range-md-pin-font-size;
}
```

`:host` means the host component, which is `ion-range`. There are two variables for background & color that we can use like this in our home.page.scss file:

```
ion-range {
    --pin-background: black;
    --pin-color: red;
}
```

Since font-family is not available as a variable, we should be able to use it directly like this:

```
ion-range {
    --pin-background: black;
    --pin-color: red;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Targeting the `:after` portion of `.range-pin` is not going to work, unfortunately because it is part of the shadow dom. You may have to figure out some other black magic to get what you want, or maybe suggest to the Ionic Team that they add the variable in a future release :-)

Comment: Sorry to reopen this issue, but the solution is not working for me, is it still how we are supposed to do it ? in global.scss and in home.scss, I've added ion-range {--pin-color: red;} but the text in the pin is still in black

Comment: I found the solution, it was just because in the html of ion-range I had color="primary", so I guess it was overwriting my pin properties. I removed this attribute and in the scss I added --bar-background.

Answer (score 1):

though my answer is not specific to your question but it may help someone as I was also stuck in this issue, I was unable to change the background color of pin and knob of ion-range because in template file, I had set color of ion-range like this

```
<ion-range color="light" class="range" pin="true" min="18" max="32" step="1" debounce="1000</ion-range>
```

so css custom properties were not working in scss

```
.range {
            --knob-size: 40px;
            --knob-background: green !important;
            --bar-background: white;
            --bar-background-active: white;
            display: block;
            height: 40px;
            padding: 0 15px;
        }
```

so **don't set the color property in template file**