# Changing ticks height in ion-range

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to implement some functions that use [`ion-range`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/range) as input. The functions are okay, my problem is related to the aesthetic issue of the `ion-range` element. Although there is this option to implement ticks in the documentation, they are the same height as the bar, making them very difficult to see if the primary color of the app is not dark enough.

I managed to modify it through the dev console and was able to acquire the style I wanted. I tried to modify the `.range-tick` class that is created, but to no avail. I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56997990/7123439) that change the style of the range pin, but how can access this options for the range-tick?

I dev console I can see that style is currently this way:

```css
.range-tick {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc((var(--height) - var(--bar-height)) / 2);
    width: var(--bar-height);
    height: var(--bar-height);
    background: var(--bar-background-active);
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

From [this question suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982792/ionic-2-how-to-customize-ion-range) I tried to add the currently empty variable `--bar-height` in my `:root` (src/theme/variables.scss), but this don't change anything.

I want to modify the class to include this options:

```css
.range-tick {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%; // <-- Changed
    width: var(--bar-height);
    height: 20px; // <-- Changed
    background: var(--bar-background-active);
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

I also tried to modify the `range.md.css` and `range.ios.css` files located in  `project_folder/node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/collection/components/range/`, which looks exactly what I can see in dev console. After modify the class and recompile nothing has changed, in dev console Inspector I can see that the class is still using the initial class and not the modified one.

---

I read some comments of people in ionic forum saying that this can only be changed by Ionic team, so I created a [new issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/20426).

Comment: I have the same issue with Ionic 5, it seems you cannot directly style items within a shadow DOM.

Comment: For Ionic 5 you can change some styles if they were exposed as a part: https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-shadow-parts#shadow-parts-explained

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS Shadow Parts.

1. To set the style for all non active ticks

```
ion-range::part(tick){
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    top: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

2. To set the style of all active ticks

```
ion-range::part(tick-active){
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    top: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

For more you can refer https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/range#css-shadow-parts

Comment: You can only use shadow parts for Ionic 5, as far as I can see Ionic 4 don't support this feature: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v4/api/range#css-custom-properties

Comment: Have tried with Ionic 6. It works.